# How to get Shipping data in magento

Tags: magento, collections

I am trying to get shipping data but getting blank

```
$orderID = 100000062;
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderID);
        foreach ($order->getShipmentsCollection() as $shipment) {
            Mage::log($shipment->getData()); 
        }
```

Comment: try to `var_dump($shipment->getData());`

Comment: i am getting  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
$shipmentCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection')
                ->setOrderFilter($order)
                ->load();
```